# Avoiding itertuples and predefined numpy arrays when iterating pandas dataframe quickly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extend the first dataframe based on the information in the second without using itertuples() as it takes too long.

The first dataframe contains data of special events, lets say an avalanche going down in a ski resort. **In the end I want to correlate the mass of the avalanche to available status data from the city**, like temperature or amount of snow. All status data from all cities is in one DataFrame. All information on the avalanche is in the other DataFrame, which I would like to extend by the status data **IF the status data was collected on the same day in the same city at an earlier time.**

Here is the setup, I hope it is easy to understand/paste:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

status = pd.DataFrame({'location': {0: 'Silvretta', 1: 'Landeck', 2: 'Silvretta', 3: 'Landeck', 4: 'Silvretta', 5: 'Landeck', 6: 'Silvretta', 7: 'Landeck'}, 'date': {0: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 1: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 2: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 3: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 4: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), 5: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), 6: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), 7: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31)}, 'time': {0: datetime.time(8, 0), 1: datetime.time(8, 0), 2: datetime.time(20, 0), 3: datetime.time(20, 0), 4: datetime.time(8, 0), 5: datetime.time(8, 0), 6: datetime.time(20, 0), 7: datetime.time(20, 0)}, 'wind_lvl': {0: 8, 1: 5, 2: 10, 3: 7, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 2, 7: 1}, 'snow_lvl': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 7, 3: 9, 4: 4, 5: 0, 6: 4, 7: 4}, 'number_skiers': {0: 26, 1: 87, 2: 8, 3: 25, 4: 90, 5: 86, 6: 55, 7: 31}})

avalanches = pd.DataFrame({'location': {0: 'Silvretta', 1: 'Landeck', 2: 'Silvretta', 3: 'Silvretta'}, 'date': {0: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 1: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 2: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), 3: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31)}, 'time': {0: datetime.time(7, 35), 1: datetime.time(12, 37), 2: datetime.time(12, 42), 3: datetime.time(23, 12)}, 'mass': {0: 10, 1: 15, 2: 8, 3: 7}})
```

Now with itertuples I can do the following, non-pythonic loop:

```
wind_lvls = np.full(len(avalanches), np.nan)
snow_lvls = np.full(len(avalanches), np.nan)
number_ski = np.full(len(avalanches), np.nan)

for idx, ava in enumerate(avalanches.itertuples()):
    relevant_status = status[(status.date == ava.date) & (status.location == ava.location) & (status.time < ava.time)]
    if len(relevant_status) > 0:
        wind_lvls[idx] = relevant_status.wind_lvl.iloc[-1]
        snow_lvls[idx] = relevant_status.snow_lvl.iloc[-1]
        number_ski[idx] = relevant_status.number_skiers.iloc[-1]

avalanches['wind_lvl'] = wind_lvls
avalanches['snow_lvls'] = snow_lvls
avalanches['number_ski'] = number_ski
```

This gives me the correct table `avalanches` and I can call `avalanches.dropna().corr()['mass']` which is the information that I was after - however, the process takes way too long to iterate in a non-toy dataset.

To cut the loop and all the manual specification of numpy arrays I tried the following:

```
avalanches['info'] = avalanches.apply(lambda row: status[(status.location == row.location) & (status.date == row.date) & (status.time < row.time)], axis=1)
```

This at least gives me the relevant information in a cell of the avalanche df, but I still need to get the latest row of the info and unpack it. I cannot use `avalanches['info'] = avalanches.apply(lambda row: status[(status.location == row.location) & (status.date == row.date) & (status.time < row.time)][-1], axis=1)` because there might be no match at all (which should result in NaNs). Should I just pack the whole function into a lambda function and would that actually speed up the process?

Could you help me specify a function to apply that would be faster than my itertuples() approach? I feel like I am missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I updated the `status` DataFrame with an additional row measured at 12:00 here below:

```
status = pd.DataFrame({'location': {0: 'Silvretta', 1: 'Landeck', 2: 'Silvretta', 3: 'Landeck', 4: 'Silvretta', 5: 'Landeck', 6: 'Silvretta', 7: 'Silvretta', 8: 'Landeck'}, 'date': {0: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 1: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 2: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 3: datetime.date(2022, 3, 30), 4: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), 5: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), 6: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), 7: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), 8: datetime.date(2022, 3, 31)}, 'time': {0: datetime.time(8, 0), 1: datetime.time(8, 0), 2: datetime.time(20, 0), 3: datetime.time(20, 0), 4: datetime.time(8, 0), 5: datetime.time(8, 0), 6: datetime.time(12, 0), 7: datetime.time(20, 0), 8: datetime.time(20, 0)}, 'wind_lvl': {0: 8, 1: 5, 2: 10, 3: 7, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 5, 7: 2, 8: 1}, 'snow_lvl': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 7, 3: 9, 4: 4, 5: 0, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 4}, 'number_skiers': {0: 26, 1: 87, 2: 8, 3: 25, 4: 90, 5: 86, 6: 62, 7: 55, 8: 31}})
```

Now row 2 of `avalanches` after `itertuples()` is

```
Silvretta   2022-03-31  12:42:00    8   5.0     2.0     62.0
```

The answer from @Laurent leads to

```
Silvretta   2022-03-31  12:42:00    8   8.0     4.0     90.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @Laurent who showed me to concat the dataframes into one and work on a joint dataframe. In the end I used the following:

```
avalanches = pd.concat([avalanches, status]).sort_values('time').reset_index(drop=True)

avalanches[["wind_lvl", "snow_lvl", "number_skiers"]] = avalanches.groupby(by=['location', 'date'])[["wind_lvl", "snow_lvl", "number_skiers"]].fillna(method='ffill')

avalanches.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your edits, here is one way to do it:

```py
avalanches = pd.concat([avalanches, status]).sort_values(
    by=["location", "date", "time"]
)

dfs = [
    avalanches.loc[avalanches["location"] == location, :]
    for location in avalanches["location"].unique()
]

dfs = [
    pd.concat(
        [
            df[["location", "date", "time", "mass"]],
            df[["wind_lvl", "snow_lvl", "number_skiers"]].shift(1),
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    for df in dfs
]

avalanches = pd.concat(dfs).dropna(subset="mass").sort_values(by=["time"])
```

So that:

```py
print(avalanches)

# Output
    location        date      time  mass  wind_lvl  snow_lvl  number_skiers
0  Silvretta  2022-03-30  07:35:00  10.0       NaN       NaN            NaN
1    Landeck  2022-03-30  12:37:00  15.0       5.0      11.0           87.0
2  Silvretta  2022-03-31  12:42:00   8.0       5.0       2.0           62.0
3  Silvretta  2022-03-31  23:12:00   7.0       2.0       4.0           55.0
```

Comment: Looks great, thank you so much for helping me out! I am still not exactly sure how the pipe works with lambda, but will look into this! However, I think this does not give me the latest datapoint available as the `[-1]` in the itertuples does, it basically rounds all timings down to 8:00/20:00 and merges - which works in the toy database. If the database contains an additional datapoint for Silvretta on 2022-03-31 at 12:00 the merge seems to transfer the info from 8:00.

Comment: Hey, thanks for coming back! I edited the question to include the additional status. For me this results in a difference, as your suggestion does not capture the latest status. The 20:00 is indeed successfully excluded, but it chooses the info from 8:00 instead of 12:00 which the `[-1]` approach manages.

Comment: I like the idea of concatenating the dataframes and shifting the information, but this assumes that no two avalanches occur in the time between two rows in `status`. For example, an additional avalanche at {Silvretta, 2022-03-31, 23:14:00, 10} would break this approach. If the info columns would be extended along their respective column over NaNs instead of shifting it should work. Just replace `.shift(1)` with `.fillna(method='ffill')` and I can accept this. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I just realized that your method has no constraint on the `date`. If there were an avalanche on {Silvretta, 2022-03-31, 7:14:00, 10} it would pick the latest information being the one from the day before. As I stated, I only want to pick the info if the status data was collected on the same day in the same city at an earlier time. In the end I used a `groupby` on the joint dataframe which seems to work (see separate answer below).

Comment: It's all good then, glad I could help a bit on your interesting question. Cheers.